# MS Project: Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks is null in the Team Planner View

Tags: vba, ms-project

I select a task in the Team Planner view. The  Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks field is null. I would expect it to list the selected tasks. Is it a bug or by design? If by design, how do I get the selected task? MS Project 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSelection.Tasks` requires a ***task view*** which Team Planner is not. Examples of where this method can be used are: Gantt Chart, Task Usage, Task Sheet.

(Note: there may not be a way to get the active selection in the Team Planner view; the Microsoft Project public api is often not as complete as one would like.)